# NextJS - API route always returns status code 200

Tags: typescript, routes, next.js, fetch, next-auth

Fairly new to nextjs, and I've come across an issue when trying to fetch an api. The API itself is fairly simple and checks if there is a session (user is logged in) and then returns a JSON with a GET. This is the getGoal/route.ts API file:

```
import { getAuthSession } from "@/lib/auth";
import { db } from "@/lib/db";

export async function GET(req: Request) {
    try {
        // Get the user session using NextAuth.js getAuthSession function
        const session = await getAuthSession();

        if (!session?.user) {
            // User is not logged in, return an error response
            return new Response("User is not logged in", {
                status: 401, // Unauthorized
            });
        }

        // Retrieve user ID from the session object
        const userId = session.user.id;

        // Fetch goals associated with the user ID
        const goals = await db.goal.findMany({
            where: {
                userId: userId,
            },
        });

        return new Response(JSON.stringify(goals), {
            status: 200,
        });
        
        
    } catch (error) {
        // Handle any other errors that occur during the request
        console.error(error);

        return new Response("Internal Server Error", {
            status: 500,
        });
    }
}
```

If i access this code in my browser http://localhost:3000/api/getGoal, it returns the 401 message with User not logged in, if im not logged in and it returns the json if I am logged in.
However, if i then try and fetch this API in my page.tsx:

```
import ProgressBar from '@/components/ProgressBar';

async function getData() {

  const data = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/goal')
  console.log(data.status)
  
  if (data.status !== 200) {
    throw new Error(data.statusText)
  }

  return data.json()


}


export default async function Home(){


    const goals = await getData()

    return (
      <div className='flex justify-center items-center'>
        <ProgressBar goals={goals} />
      </div>
    );
};
```

And if I `console.log` the `data.status`, it always returns a status code of 200 and always shows the data.
I think I'm missing something here, but I just can't seem to wrap my head around it.
Again, I am fairly new to Nextjs and React in general.

I've tried different types of catch clauses. I've tried asking chatgpt. I've tried looking around for tutorials.
I expect it to show the data only if a user is logged in (there is a session).

Comment: You need to use `NextResponse`, not `Response`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NextResponse as mentioned in [nextjs doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/next-response#json).

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
export async function GET(req: Request) {
  try {
    // ... you code
    const goals = {};
    return NextResponse.json(goals, {
      status: 200,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    // Handle any other errors that occur during the request
    console.error(error);
    return NextResponse.json({"error": "Internal Server Error"}, {
      status: 500,
    });
  }
}
```